# Custom compile sqlite as php so

Tags: php, compiling, sqlite3

In [Compile sqlite with soundex feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548953/compile-sqlite-with-soundex-feature) I learned how to do a custom compile of sqlite.  While this was a step towards my goal of using sqlite's soundex in a functional test, I find I'm not there yet.  I need to replace the existing `sqlite.so`.  Various efforts to modify this command:

```
$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY=1 -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE=1 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX"
```

have failed.  Installing `php5-dev` and running `phpize` in the sqlite source code directory results in

> Cannot find config.m4

While corrections to my procedure will be very welcome, I'd also like to find some more complete references on how to get to where I want to go.  I'm just ignorant, not stupid.  For example, where would I have found out that the `D` was required before the sqlite feature `SQLITE_SOUNDEX`?

[EDIT: partial answer =  [use of the GNU compilers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), assuming I knew that CFLAGS are gcc options, to use a preprocessor option, and that the sqlite feature should be considered a macro.]

[CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) and [CompilingSoftware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware) are insufficient.  [Building PHP extensions](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_extensions.html) doesn't seem to help much either.

Comment: The `./configure` step only prepares the build environment - did you actually run `make` and `sudo make install` after? (Actually FWIW I would suggest installing `checkinstall` and replacing the last command with `sudo checkinstall` so as to keep everything under control of the package management system.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu you have two packages for SQLite: `sqlite` and `sqlite3`. If you use the second it is compiled with support for that function (not sure if it even exists in the other version...)

```
sqlite> SELECT SOUNDEX("John"), SOUNDEX("Joahn");
J500|J500
```

So first try to use the second version:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove sqlite
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Now to you question: I have tried to compile it and it seems to work:

- Download SQLite source code from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). I used `sqlite-autoconf`
- Extract and run the configure command **without sudo**. You will only need that later

  ```
  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY=1 -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE=1 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX"
  ```
- Compile SQLite

  ```
  $ make
  ```
- Test it

  ```
  $ ./sqlite3
  sqlite> SELECT SOUNDEX("John"), SOUNDEX("Joahn");
  J500|J500
  ```
- Install it in your system

  ```
  $ sudo make install
  ```

Comment: As it turns out I had assumed that my Ubuntu VM would behave the same as my Windows host and complain that there was no `soundex()1 function.  After all, the SQLite docs said it was not compiled by default.  So when I got around to running my test in PHP, prompted by your response, it turns out that SQLite docs were not correct.  You were.  Thanks!